# Regex which matches anchor tags wrapping an url

Tags: regex

I have following text:

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
<a href="https://google.com">website</a>
<a href="https://google.com"><em>https://google.com</em></a>
```

which I want to transform into:

```
https://google.com
<a href="https://google.com">website</a>
<em>https://google.com</em>
```

by replacing anchor tags which contain urls with just the url.

i came this far: `<a.*?href="http.*?>(.*?)<\/a>` but struggle making the group more strict. it should check for the `http` string and allow wrapping tags such as `<em>`.

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First, what language are you working with? Second, are you saying that `<a href="https://google.com">website</a>` should not be transformed because `website` is not a URL?

Comment: JavaScript, with this `text.replace(/<a.*?href="http.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g, '$1')`.

Yes `<a href="https://google.com">website</a>` should not be transformed because website is not a URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with:

```
// your code goes here
var s =
  '<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com">  website  </a>\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com">website</a>\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com"><em>https://google.com</em></a>\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com">  <em>https://google.com</em>  </a>\n' +
  '<a href="https://www.google.com">\n' +
  '  <em>https://www.google.com</em>\n' +
  '</a>\n';

 var re = /<a\s+href="([^"]+)"\s*>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/a>/isg;
 var new_s = s.replace(re, function(match, p1, p2) {
    if (p2.indexOf('http') == -1)
        return match; /* in effect, no substritution */
    return p2;
 });
console.log(new_s);
```

[See demo](http://ideone.com/n3TV1j)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Argument02)

```js
let str = `<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
<a href="https://google.com">website</a>
<a href="https://google.com"><em>https://google.com</em></a>`

let html = new DOMParser()

let parsed = html.parseFromString(str, 'text/html')

let final = [...parsed.getElementsByTagName('a')].map(tag=>{
  let href = tag.href
  if(tag.innerHTML.includes(tag.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
    return tag.innerHTML
  }
  return tag
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: thanks for the example. `str` can have more text in between (not being html), e.g.:

`<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a> and
<a href="https://google.com">website</a> and
<a href="https://google.com"><em>https://google.com</em></a>`

Comment: @Koji these example strings are already considered inside `str`, and it's replacing them to change to desired format already,

Comment: thanks, `final` should return the full text and not only the links. I also use node.js and would have to use something like jsdom which feels not ideal. what's your thought on this?

Comment: @Koji it does return the complete text, see `tag.innerHTML` if you just need text you can return `tag.innerText`, it's always better to use HTML parser instead of regex